# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python, json, python-requests

When I try to use the [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) method of a response object from the *requests* library, I get an error:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://example.com/myfile.json")
>>> response_json = response.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: What version of `requests` are you using? `print requests.__version__`.

Comment: This is what I did `try:
        print requests.__version
        return int(req.json['statistics']['dataCount'])` And I got error message as `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version'
`

Comment: @AKIWEB, he said `requests.__version__` not `requests.__version`

Comment: @AKIWEB, The change he talks about happened in [1.0.0](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#100-2012-12-17)

Comment: Thanks for correcting.. I got this version `0.8.2`. is there anything wrong with this version? Now what should I do?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Any thoughts what should I do?

Comment: You have an extremely old version of `requests` installed. You should upgrade to a more recent version if you want to use the JSON features (which were first added in 0.12.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your version of the `requests` library is too old. JSON support was added in version 0.12.1, released nearly 2 years ago.

The currently released version is 2.2.1.

Comment: Thanks. How would I update this in my Ubuntu machine? Any idea?

Comment: @AKIWEB: I'm guessing you are using [Ubuntu Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-requests)? Use a `virtualenv` and install a new version into that? Alternatively, use a backport of a newer Ubuntu package.

Comment: I am not sure as this machine was provided to me by unix folks in our company.. Is there no way I can update this library directly in my ubuntu machine?

Comment: It's a Ubuntu package you have; a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) will give you a private area to *easily* install library versions that you need to get your project working. The Ubuntu packages are way out of date, and I doubt you are going to get them updated.

Comment: pip install requests --upgrade